# Getting hardware information in MATLAB in a platform-independent way

Tags: java, matlab

I would like to find hardware information such as the hardware ID, manufacturer and type of graphics card, CPU type etc. from within MATLAB. Preferably without installing any additional toolbox or third-party scripts.

I assume this could be done by directly accessing the Java interface.

Comment: In Windows, I manually open the device manager to see those info, and under Mac or Linux ( I do not have access to them now), I believe something like (system(''cat /proc/') will do the job. But this is NOT platform independent.

Comment: Getting this in a platform-independent way will be quite a challenge I assume. Alternatively, you could query the OS and run the OS-specific checks then. E.g. on Windows, you can use `[status,info] = system('systeminfo')` and find the relevant information.

Comment: As you can see, `system('systeminfo')` does not reveal the graphics card info, which was the most important information. It would be nice to interface with `devmgmt.msc` though.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very easy to do this in a platform-independent way.

I would start by taking a look at [cpuinfo](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33155-cpu-info) from the MATLABCentral File Exchange. This does quite a bit of what you're asking for (although not everything). It does it by including separate code paths for Windows, Unix and Mac, and running the appropriate commands on each.

It's a third-party script, which I know you specified that you didn't want, but it is freely available and authored by a MathWorks developer - and even if you can't use it directly, you could perhaps at least read through it to see how you might proceed to implement things yourself.

Comment: That link is ok, but it only provides CPU information. I also need Graphics Card information for this. Calling different commands is great, though not as neat as calling some (maybe undocumented) java interface in MATLAB. Thanks! @sam-roberts

Comment: If you need to find information about the graphics card, you could use the command `gpuDevice`, which works across all platforms. `gpuDevice` is part of Parallel Computing Toolbox. I'm not sure of your needs, but perhaps you're looking to find out GPU info because you'd like to do GPU computation, in which case you'll almost certainly have PCT available. To make things run even if PCT isn't present, you could wrap the call to PCT within a check to see whether PCT is present, using the command `ver('distcomp')`.

Comment: Actually I was running OpenGL commands (via Psychtoolbox-3), so different graphics card matters. But it is almost irrelevant with PCT, and would be too much to get PCT just to do that. @Sam Roberts